# How to perform incremental tar backup of FAT filesystem

Tags: backup, tar, fat

I use `tar --listed-incremental=...` to perform incremental backups on my computer, and for the most part it works like a charm.  However, it doesn't seem to play well with my old FAT partition.  It thinks that all the files have changed and backs up everything.  I read somewhere that tar incremental backups rely on inodes, and that's why it doesn't work well with FAT.  Is there a way to fake it, or force it to just use name and modification date instead of inode?

Comment: Is there a reason someone voted to close this question?  Please leave a comment when you do so.

Comment: Never mind.  I decided to buckle down and convert the file system to ext4.  FAT was causing nothing but problems.

Comment: I have the same problem :-( So far I bypass it with option `--newer, --after-date DATE-OR-FILE` which is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tar and --newer / --after-date parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108230/tar-and-newer-after-date-parameter)