# Tar and --newer / --after-date parameter

Tags: windows, shell, tar

My project structure is the following:

```
-sprint41
 -file1
 -file2
-sprint40
 -file1
 -file2
```

- All my files(+ sprint41) in sprint41 folder have a modified date 20130807
- All my files(+ sprint40) in sprint40 folder have a modified date
  20130610

I want to create an archive including all the files(+folder) after 20130715.
My command is the following:

```
tar -cf test.tar --after-date 20130715 *
```

After this command, test.tar contains the following:

```
-sprint41
 -file1
 -file2
-sprint40
```

It is keeping sprint40 folder even though the modified date is before 20130715

**I am expecting to have the following:**

```
-sprint41
 -file1
 -file2
```

Do you have a clue ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the problem is that tar will still include the directories even if they are empty.  It's only really checking the --newer option on files, not directories.  Going to have to either write a small script or use find with -cnewer and pipe the output into tar (with --no-recursion on tar command).

Create a file with the timestamp you want with

```
 touch -t 201307150000 timefile.txt
```

Then Somthing like:

```
find . -cnewer timefile.txt -print0 | xargs -0 tar --no-recursion -cf test.tar
```

Comment: Sounds good, but i forgot to mention that i am running tar command under windows. Find is pretty limited under windows. Not sure if i can find by date like that

Comment: Ah, well that changes things.  Do you have PowerShell installed? Not entirely sure on syntax there but I know that extends quite a bit of functionality.

Comment: I ended up using Xcopy with a date parameter, then tar the directory, thanks in any case, +1